# R - creating a sequential dummy variable index array?

Tags: python, r, dictionary, categorical-data

I have a column in a datatable with unique values that are non-sequential, say `[1,2,3,100,101,200]` but what I would like is `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` (or `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` for R with its 1 first index.) In python, I could do something simple like:

```py
lookup = {elem:idx for idx,elem in enumerate(column)}
reverse_lookup = {idx:elem for idx,elem in enumerate(column)} 
idx_array = [lookup[elem] for elem in column]
```

Is there a simple way to do this in R?

Edit: Thanks to comment/answer, I've used the `seq_along` function:

```
c_idx <- seq_along(unique(off$callgroup))
c_val <- unique(off$callgroup)

a_idx <- seq_along(unique(off$agent_idx))
a_val <- unique(off$agent_idx)
```

As you can see, I have four arrays. c_idx is an array of unique values, and c_val is their sequential indices (same design for agent_idx via a_idx & a_val). In my datatable there are multiple instances of any given c_val and/or a_val.

Is there a way to swap the value out? (R sees a given value for c_val, retrieves the index, retrieves the value in c_idx under the same index, and swaps them on the datatable?)

Apparently, this does not produce the desired effect:

```
off2$callgroup <-  replace(off$callgroup,c_val,c_idx)
off2$agent_idx <-  replace(off$agent_idx,a_val,a_idx)
```

Namely, because, the second element should be a list of true indices. Whereas these aren't indices, rather they're values.

Comment: Does this answer? https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/R/functions/seq_along

Comment: This is perfect! Post as an answer and I'll upvote/checkmark, assuming you're interested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the commented link, this can be achieved with `seq_along` eg `seq_along(4:10)` :)
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/R/functions/seq_along

Comment: I made a slight edit to the post, if you have any ideas, great! If not, no worries